# What is the use case for a same column to have both a foreign and primary key referencing same column on own table

Tags: sql, oracle

recently I came across the following situation where I found that Oracle SQL allows me to do this:

```
CREATE TABLE PRUEBA (
   id int PRIMARY KEY,
   FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES PRUEBA (id)
);
```

Does this have any useful usage? If one wanted to reference to the same table would do:

```
CREATE TABLE PRUEBA (
   id int PRIMARY KEY,
   parent int,
   FOREIGN KEY (parent) REFERENCES PRUEBA (id)
);
```

I'm confused why is this allowed, maybe there is one scenario where this could be useful.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think there is actually a *useful* scenario for such a relationship.  However, banning it seems arbitrary.  Obviously a table can have a foreign key to itself.  That it is the same column is just falls out of what is allowed.

Comment: I can't think of a use for that first table with the keys specified. It is a list of IDs and the records don't describe a relationship, like the 2nd table example, so no need for the FK.

Comment: That's an entity that has a 1:1 relationship with itself... that has a 1:1 relationship with itself... that has a 1:1 relationship with itself... ad infinitum. I don't see a use for it. It's perfectly legal SQL, though.

Comment: While the construct in the first example is idiotic, it raises an interesting question... In what order would the conditions be checked? If Oracle tries to enforce the FK condition first, that will fail, since the value doesn't exist in the PK index yet. (Of course, the question can be answered easily by experimentation: the insert doesn't fail, which means that the PK is handled first, and only then the FK condition.)